# Flying insects on olive tree

Tags: species-identification, entomology

They may be responsible for why the leaves are drying out.
Location is in West Europe.
Their size may be 0.5 cm to 1 cm

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please update with your location, approximate size of the insect, and a better image (i.e., a close-up image) to receive a proper ID. Currently, I don't think anybody can provide an accurate sub-family identification. You can use the *edit* button below your post to update your question directly. Thanks.

Comment: done @theforestecologist

Comment: Maybe some sort of olive fruit fly

Comment: They look like three different kinds of insect. I have no identification for any of them.

Comment: All of the insects in the uppermost photo are parasitoid Hymenoptera; the smallest (and uppermost) may be from superfamily Chalcidoidea; the other two appear to be members of superfamily Proctotrupoidea (and may represent different families from that group: the elbowed antenna of the second reminds me of the family Diapriidae; the straight antenna of the third recalls Proctotrupidae).